# Multiple -notmatch strings in powershell

Tags: powershell, regex

I am struggeling to combine `-notmatch` expressions using powershell, just like what I do under Linux e.g. with `grep -v "/aaa/" | grep -v "/bbb/"`. In other words I have the input `in.txt` looking as follows:

```
/aaa
/aaa/x.txt
/bbb
/bbb/y.txt
/ccc
/ccc/z.txt
```

I want to end up with an file `out.txt`

```
/aaa
/bbb
/ccc
/ccc/z.txt
```

What I have so far is `cat in.txt | ?{$_ -notmatch '/aaa/'}  > out.txt;`, but how do I generalize this?

PS: Yes, I searched the web for examples or manpage, but I guess I am stuck in my bubble.

#### References

- [Similar title on stackoverflow, but not clear to me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25834299/using-notmatch-with-multiple-filters)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pipe a second `-notmatch`:

```
cat in.txt | ?{$_ -notmatch '/aaa/'} | ?{$_ -notmatch '/bbb/'} > out.txt;
```

Or to shorten it:

```
cat in.txt | ?{$_ -notmatch '/aaa/|/bbb/'}  > out.txt;
```

It should produce your expected result.

Comment: So there is no shorter solution e.g. within the same `-notmatch` expression?

Comment: @B--rian See edit.